# How to change an Index of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have a DataFrame with an index column as [0, 1,2,3]. I would like to change it to ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']. How do I do this? I do not want to introduce a new column but change index only.

I tried
qtrs = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
and
df.reindex(qtrs)
where df is the DataFrame.

It does not work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite the index using a list comprehension:

```
df.index = [f'Q{(i%4)+1}' for i in df.index]
```

This might be more sophisticated than you need; it will deal with index values greater than 3. If that's not an issue, just use

```
df.index = [f'Q{i+1}' for i in df.index]
```

If your values are actually strings, not integers, you'll have to convert them:

```
df.index = [f'Q{(int(i)%4)+1}' for i in df.index]
```